# Hiding div clicking on other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have four button and four div above it. 
I want to only one div at time , but keep showed the four button.

Here it is the html for buttons

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<a><p id="firstBtn" class="mediabutton"><span class="icon"></span>button1</p></a> <!-- 1st button -->
<div id="firstDiv" class="mediaoptions" >
... <!-- stuff of the div -->
</div>

 <a><p id="sndBtn" class="mediabutton active"><span class="icon"></span>button2</p></a> <!-- 2st button -->
<div id="sndDiv" class="mediaoptions" >
... <!-- stuff of the div -->
</div>
```

This is how I can recogniz which button was clicked

**Javascript**

```
$("container").click(function(event){
var that = event.target.id;
 if(((that == "firstBtn") || (that == "sndBtn") || (that == "trdBtn") || (that == "fourBtn") )
    &&  !($("#"+that).hasClass("active"))
)
{
    //Here comes the stuff
}
});
```

Now. The `active` class let the button to be Highlighted. I want only one button highlight.
The `sndDiv` is set on `display : block` , the others are set on `display: none`.

Making a recap : I want to press a button , show the div above it and hide everybody else. I tried really a lot of stuff, but i failed.

Sorry for my english, Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `Btn` with `Div`, and you have the element you'd like to show, the others have a common class and are easy to target :

```
$("#container").on('click', '.mediabutton', function(event){
    var that = event.target.id,
        elem = $('#' + that.replace('Btn','Div'));

    if( !$("#"+that).hasClass("active") ) {
        $('.mediaoptions').not(elem).hide();
        elem.show()
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually now I have a problem : there is also a `span` , as you can see, and when I click on it , the thing does not work out. How I can make it work even if I click on `span` or `p` ?

Comment: try replacing `event.target.id` with `this.id` and see if that works!

Comment: It does perfectly! I would like to get the difference.
PS : Is `event` now useless?

Comment: Nope, the events target is the element that was actually clicked, i.e. if you click the `span`, `event.target` **is** the span. `this` is the element that was bound, so if you click the `span`, `this` is still `.mediabutton`, as the event bubbles up to the bound element.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
$("container").click(function(event){
    var that = event.target.id;
    if(((that == "firstBtn") || (that == "sndBtn") || (that == "trdBtn") || (that == "fourBtn") ) &&  !($("#"+that).hasClass("active")))
    {
        $('.mediaoptions').show();
        $('#'+that.replace('Btn','Div')).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to just point you to a link, but I created a really lightweight jQuery script to handle stuff like this that you might found useful: http://cferdinandi.github.com/tabby/.

You may find it easier to just repurpose that than try to modify your existing code to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually developed a very similar for my purpose. I'm having some issue , but I appreciate your advice. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Don't jQuery .hide() and .show() do the job?

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Kind of but it doesn't automaticly hide all other items.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second line below to your javascript and see what is alerted:

```
var that = event.target.id;
alert(that);
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish perhaps something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('.mediaoptions').hide(); $('#sndDiv').show(); return false;"><p id="sndBtn" class="mediabutton active"><span class="icon"></span>button2</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Mjm/). I made some updates on javascript and html;

```
$(".mediabutton").click(function(event){
 $(".mediabutton").removeClass("active");
 $(this).addClass("active");

 $(".mediaoptions").hide();
 $("#"+$(this).data("target-div")).show();
});
```

Comment: I add a `data-target-id` to button, it means the div that must be shown/hidden

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CtqUU/

With this you can have as many `<div>` and `<button>` elements as you want.  Change `class` names and `id` as needed to fit what you need.

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden" id="box1">Box 1</div>
<button value="box1">Box 1</button>
<div class="hidden" id="box2">Box 2</div>
<button value="box2">Box 2</button>
```

CSS:

```
    div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

JS:

```
    $("button").click(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("div").addClass("hidden");
        $("#"+val).removeClass("hidden");
    });
```